# What does the command nautilus -q do?

Tags: command-line, nautilus

I ran these commands...

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:costales/folder-color
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install folder-color
nautilus -q
```

...to get folder color to work.  When I ran nautilus -q my desktop acted weird for a minute, and now seems to be working fine.  Can anyone tell me what the command nautilus -q means/did?

I found these commands from here [How to change folders color?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134997/how-to-change-folders-color)

Comment: Check out `nautilus -h`.

Comment: check it our where?

Comment: @ShawnMoore run `nautilus -h` on the command line

Comment: @wjandrea what will that do?  what does this command mean?

Comment: @ShawnMoore Ironically, you can run it to find out. But seriously, `-h` or `--help` gets the help page for `nautilus`, as with most commands (also e.g. `apt -h`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nautilus -q`simply quits nautilus